# EV3 software crashes on Windows 8 laptop

Tags: ev3, bluetooth

My cousin has Windows 8 x64 netbook laptop. When he tries to start the application he gets .NET framework error and I can see following text in the log file:

```
+000,016 >> MINDSTORMS EV3 launched at 2015-12-27_12-31-07-odp.
+000,016 >> OS Type: Windows
+000,031 >> OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
+000,031 >> OS Bitness: 64-bit
+000,063 >> MINDSTORMS EV3 assembly file version: 1.0.11021.3
+000,063 >> MINDSTORMS EV3 build drop: R1-X3-Dev[GC]_20141021.3
+004,349 >> Bluetooth supported: True
+004,352 >> Bluetooth Primary Radio Information:
+004,352 >>     Manufacturer: RalinkTechnology
+004,352 >>     Software Manufacturer: IvtBlueSoleilXxxx
+004,352 >>     Stack Factory: InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.BluetoothPublicFactory
+004,352 >>     Hardware Status: Running
+004,352 >>     Mode: PowerOff
+004,352 >>     Class: 10C
+004,352 >>     Local Address: 543530126E3A
+004,508 >> Enabling passive scan for TCP;USB
+005,618 >> Unhandled exception occurred at 2015-12-27_12-31-12-odp.
InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.BlueSoleil.BlueSoleilSocketException (0x80004005): Došlo k pokusu o operaci s něčím, co není soket (BlueSoleil: FUNCTION_NOTSUPPORT (0x0308)).
   in InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.BlueSoleil.BluesoleilUtils.CheckAndThrow(BtSdkError ret, String descr)
   in InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.BlueSoleil.BluesoleilFactory.BluesoleilInquiry.<>c__DisplayClass3.<BeginInquiry>b__2()
   in InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.Factory.CommonBluetoothInquiry`1.BeginInquiry(Int32 maxDevices, TimeSpan inquiryLength, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object state, LiveDiscoveryCallback liveDiscoHandler, Object liveDiscoState, ThreadStart startInquiry, DiscoDevsParams args)
   in InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.BlueSoleil.BluesoleilFactory.BluesoleilInquiry.BeginInquiry(Int32 maxDevices, TimeSpan inquiryLength, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, LiveDiscoveryCallback liveDiscoHandler, Object liveDiscoState, DiscoDevsParams args)
   in InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.BlueSoleil.BluesoleilClient.BeginInquiry(Int32 maxDevices, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, LiveDiscoveryCallback liveDiscoHandler, Object liveDiscoState, DiscoDevsParams args)
   in InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.Factory.CommonDiscoveryBluetoothClient.BeginDiscoverDevices(Int32 maxDevices, Boolean authenticated, Boolean remembered, Boolean unknown, Boolean discoverableOnly, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, LiveDiscoveryCallback liveDiscoHandler, Object liveDiscoState)
   in InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.Factory.CommonDiscoveryBluetoothClient.DiscoverDevices(Int32 maxDevices, Boolean authenticated, Boolean remembered, Boolean unknown, Boolean discoverableOnly)
   in NationalInstruments.Casper.BthDeviceDiscoveryService.ForceActiveScan(IEnumerable`1 transports)
   in NationalInstruments.Casper.DiscoveryManager.ForceActiveScan(IEnumerable`1 transports)
   in NationalInstruments.X3.BrickServerService.Core.PBrickDevice.<StartDiscovery>b__8(Object param0)
   in System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   in System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   in System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   in System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
Stack trace with ILOffsets:
   at InTheHand.Net.Personal.dll.BluesoleilUtils.CheckAndThrow  (IL offset: 0x70)
   at InTheHand.Net.Personal.dll.<>c__DisplayClass3.<BeginInquiry>b__2  (IL offset: 0x23)
   at InTheHand.Net.Personal.dll.CommonBluetoothInquiry`1.BeginInquiry  (IL offset: 0x9a)
   at InTheHand.Net.Personal.dll.BluesoleilInquiry.BeginInquiry  (IL offset: 0x4c)
   at InTheHand.Net.Personal.dll.BluesoleilClient.BeginInquiry  (IL offset: 0x0)
   at InTheHand.Net.Personal.dll.CommonDiscoveryBluetoothClient.BeginDiscoverDevices  (IL offset: 0x35)
   at InTheHand.Net.Personal.dll.CommonDiscoveryBluetoothClient.DiscoverDevices  (IL offset: 0x0)
   at NationalInstruments.X3.Casper.dll.BthDeviceDiscoveryService.ForceActiveScan  (IL offset: 0x4a)
   at NationalInstruments.X3.Casper.dll.DiscoveryManager.ForceActiveScan  (IL offset: 0x16)
   at NationalInstruments.X3.BrickServerService.Core.dll.PBrickDevice.<StartDiscovery>b__8  (IL offset: 0x0)
   at mscorlib.dll.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context  (IL offset: 0xe)
   at mscorlib.dll.ExecutionContext.RunInternal  (IL offset: 0x70)
   at mscorlib.dll.ExecutionContext.Run  (IL offset: 0x0)
   at mscorlib.dll.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem  (IL offset: 0x23)
   at mscorlib.dll.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch  (IL offset: 0x9d)
   at mscorlib.dll._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback  (IL offset: 0x0)
```

I was able to get the error number for the Czech error text along with it's English version:

> [#10038 Socket operation on nonsocket.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#wsaenotsock)

I guess it's something bluetooth related. The program version is `1.1.1` (`20141021.3`) and the corresponding installer name is `LMS-EV3-WIN32-ENUS-01-01-01-full-setup.exe`.

How could I fix that? Any workaround is appreciated.

Comment: Similar error appears when attempting to run multiple instances of the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it sounds like it does not like your Bluetooth for some reason. Usually, there is a physical switch on laptops that let you disable bluetooth. If there is not a physical switch, there should be a way to do it via software, either via the bluetooth notification tray icon or special Bluetooth software that came with the laptop.

Try turning off/disabling Bluetooth and then start the EV3 software.

Also, be sure to send this crash report to LEGO technical support.

Comment: Actually, we found out that bluetooth was off. There's no switch though, so we found it in computer settings. After enabling and pairing bluetooth, the error does not appear most often. Still I was unable to reliably reproduce it.